# Luigi Task Visualiser Dependency Graph is empty

Tags: python-2.7, luigi

Am new to Luigi.

Below python (2.7) code able to run successful using --local-scheduler. However if run under central scheduler, there is no dependency graph nor workers. Please advice

The dependency of the code:

AllTasks class will trigger CountLetters class. CountLetters class will read word value and length and output to a file named word_count.txt (e.g apple_count.txt).

**python code**

```
class AllTasks(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        words = ['apple','banana','grapefruit']
        for word in words:
            yield CountLetters(word=word)

class CountLetters(luigi.Task):
    word=luigi.Parameter()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('{}_count.txt'.format(self.word))

    def run(self):
        with self.output().open('w') as outfile:
            outfile.write(
                    '{word} | {letter_count}\n'.format(
                        word=self.word,
                        letter_count=len(self.word)
                    )
            )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    luigi.run()
```

**local scheduler**

`PYTHONPATH="." luigi --module luigi_test AllTasks --local-scheduler`

```
DEBUG: Checking if AllTasks() is complete
DEBUG: Checking if CountLetters(word=apple) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if CountLetters(word=banana) is complete
DEBUG: Checking if CountLetters(word=grapefruit) is complete
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   AllTasks__99914b932b   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_grapefruit_b871f9bf08   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_banana_db7b170113   has status   PENDING
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_apple_946b133f4a   has status   PENDING
INFO: Done scheduling tasks
INFO: Running Worker with 1 processes
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 4
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) running   CountLetters(word=apple)
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) done      CountLetters(word=apple)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_apple_946b133f4a   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 3
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) running   CountLetters(word=banana)
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) done      CountLetters(word=banana)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_banana_db7b170113   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 2
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) running   CountLetters(word=grapefruit)
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) done      CountLetters(word=grapefruit)
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   CountLetters_grapefruit_b871f9bf08   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Pending tasks: 1
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) running   AllTasks()
INFO: [pid 22933] Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) done      AllTasks()
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   AllTasks__99914b932b   has status   DONE
DEBUG: Asking scheduler for work...
DEBUG: Done
DEBUG: There are no more tasks to run at this time
INFO: Worker Worker(salt=271153046, workers=1, host=gary.mlp.com, username=root, pid=22933) was stopped. Shutting down Keep-Alive thread
INFO: 
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 4 tasks of which:
* 4 ran successfully:
    - 1 AllTasks()
    - 3 CountLetters(word=apple,banana,grapefruit)

This progress looks :) because there were no failed tasks or missing dependencies

===== Luigi Execution Summary =====
```

**http://localhost:8082/static/visualiser/index.html**

`luigid`

```
2020-02-28 21:08:56,137 luigi[22994] INFO: logging configured by default settings
2020-02-28 21:08:56,147 luigi.scheduler[22994] INFO: No prior state file exists at /var/lib/luigi-server/state.pickle. Starting with empty state
2020-02-28 21:08:56,156 luigi.server[22994] INFO: Scheduler starting up
2020-02-28 21:09:53,847 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/index.html (::1) 32.42ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,933 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/css/luigi.css (::1) 1.64ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,937 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/jquery-1.10.0.min.js (::1) 2.53ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,942 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css (::1) 2.59ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,945 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/bootstrap3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css (::1) 1.85ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,949 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/bootstrap3/js/bootstrap.min.js (::1) 2.28ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,953 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/css/tipsy.css (::1) 2.02ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,956 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/css/font-awesome.min.css (::1) 1.92ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,960 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/AdminLTE/css/skin-green-light.min.css (::1) 1.94ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,963 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/datatables/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css (::1) 2.03ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,968 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/d3/d3.min.js (::1) 2.75ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,972 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/bootstrap-toggle/css/bootstrap-toggle.min.css (::1) 2.20ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,975 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/AdminLTE/css/AdminLTE.min.css (::1) 2.07ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,979 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/d3/dagre-d3.min.js (::1) 2.42ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,983 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/mustache.js (::1) 2.56ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,987 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/js/graph.js (::1) 2.39ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,991 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/js/luigi.js (::1) 2.25ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,995 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/js/visualiserApp.js (::1) 1.76ms
2020-02-28 21:09:53,998 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/js/tipsy.js (::1) 1.85ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,001 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/jquery.slimscroll.min.js (::1) 2.32ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,005 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/AdminLTE/js/app.min.js (::1) 1.86ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,008 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js (::1) 2.09ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,013 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js (::1) 2.51ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,017 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/URI/1.18.2/URI.js (::1) 2.41ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,297 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/has_task_history?data=%7B%7D (::1) 8.48ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,302 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/is_pause_enabled?data=%7B%7D (::1) 4.09ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,309 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/worker_list?data=%7B%7D (::1) 4.56ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,313 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/resource_list?data=%7B%7D (::1) 3.81ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,428 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /static/visualiser/lib/datatables/images/sort_both.png (::1) 2.14ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,519 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22RUNNING%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 4.77ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,525 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22BATCH_RUNNING%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 4.65ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,533 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22PENDING%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22UPSTREAM_DISABLED%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 5.00ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,538 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22FAILED%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 4.37ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,543 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22PENDING%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22UPSTREAM_FAILED%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 3.77ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,548 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22DISABLED%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 4.17ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,554 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22PENDING%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 3.73ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,559 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/task_list?data=%7B%22status%22%3A%22DONE%22%2C%22upstream_status%22%3A%22%22%2C%22search%22%3A%22%22%7D (::1) 3.68ms
2020-02-28 21:09:54,675 tornado.access[22994] INFO: 304 GET /api/is_paused?data=%7B%7D (::1) 3.77ms
```

[LTV Task List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVvyt.png)

[LTV Dependency Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rJDU.png)

[LTV Workers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kppNc.png)

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your browser?

Comment: I see that everything is in code 304 so your browser keep a former version. Can you try to empty your browser's cache and retry?

Comment: @rolf82, screenshots have been attached

Comment: @rolf82 I cleared cache and retry. The result is still empty dependency graph and no workers.

Answer (score 0):

The daemon `luigid` is just that, a daemon, or background process waiting for something to be scheduled. Just starting the daemon isn't going to do anything for you. What you should try to do is run `luigid` in one terminal window and then execute the tasks from another, e.g.,

```
PYTHONPATH="." luigi --module luigi_test AllTasks
```

Note that I did not include `--local-scheduler` here.

Luigi's central scheduler is for running tasks from multiple executions and ensures that no task (with equivalent parameters) is run twice. That way, if you have some regularly occuring trigger with overlapping parameters, it will save your server the computation.

Quick edit here: `luigi.run()` is deprecated. If you're actually running that file you'd want to do something like: `luigi.build([AllTasks()])`. `luigi.build` also takes in a parameter for specifying if you want to use the local scheduler or not (defaults to using central).